# Trying to find sqrt of numbers between 0 and 1 without sqrt function

Tags: c++, algorithm, sqrt

The problem I cant solve is how I find the sqrt of numbers between 0 and 1. After that I think all works. The only input numbers that make this program crash are numbers between 0(not included) and 1(not included)

Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double squareroot(double x)  /* computes the square root of x */

{
 assert( x >= 0 ); /* make sure x is not negative*/
 if (x==0) return 0;

/* the sqrt must be between xhi and xlo */
 double xhi = x;
 double xlo = 0;
 double guess = x/2;

/* We stop when guess*guess-x is very small */

 while (abs(guess*guess-x) > 0.00001 )
   {
     if (guess*guess > x)  xhi = guess;
     else xlo = guess;
     guess = (xhi + xlo)/2;
   }

 return guess;
 }

/* Test Stub */


int main()
 {
  double testvalue;
  cout << "\n Enter a TestValue= " ;
  cin >> testvalue;
  cout << endl;
  double testresult = squareroot(testvalue);
  cout << "\n Square Root= " << testresult << "\n" ;
  }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't your personal help desk. So I'd say Nope!

Comment: If the program crashes, did you try running it in a debugger to catch the crash? Otherwise, have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: It does not crash. I tried debugging it. It works pretty good, but in some point i'm missing something. And that is including the sqrt of numbers between 0 and 1 (ex. 0,4 0,1 0,7)

Comment: When I step through the code line by line, I really mean it. Using a debugger, you can stop any place you want by setting a *breakpoint*, then step line by line while watching the variables and their values. Set a breakpoint on the `squareroot` function, run in a debugger and it will stop when the function is called, step through the code and when you notice the values of the involved variables are not what you expect them to be you should know what went wrong.

Comment: What error is it crashing with?

Comment: If the program doesn't crash then edit your question and describe the real problem instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I will try your suggestion. Thank you so much for your answers.

To: StillLearning // It's my first post, I didnt know that Stackoverflow only answer topics of crashing codes. I thought the title was clear

Comment: Your assumption that the square root is between 0 and `x` is wrong when `x` is between 0 and 1. The square root of 0.5 is 0.707.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is crashing because of this line:

`while (abs(guess*guess-x) > 0.00001 )`

When you have numbers between 0 and 1, your algorithm will always result in a number greater than 0.00001 resulting in an infinite loop. A fix would be to either change your algorithm to another square root approximation technique (see Newton's method, fixed point theorem, polynomial approximation techniques, etc.).

Tip: try tracing your code to see what's happening even if you need to write it down on paper

Comment: The basic problem is the initial assumption that the square root will be between `xhi` and `xlo`. It's not true for fractions.

Comment: I was able to solve it just adding a simple IF. When x is between 0 and 1, xhi=1 and xlo=0, and the process inside the while repeats for that condition. Didnt have to change the approximation technique or all of that stuff.